# ES6&Webpack: как правильно подключить зависимую от jQuery библиотеку с IIFE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, ecmascript-6

Для корректной работы библиотеки `jquery.selection` необходимо, чтобы функционал `jquery` был уже загружен, так как в `jquery.selection` есть функция, вызываемая при загрузке (т. н. `Immediately-Invoked Function Expression - Немедленно вызываемое функциональное выражение). Обычно, это достигается так:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.selection.min.js">
```

Но что, если мы используем `webpack`?

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.selection';
```

Хотя Webpack отработает без ошибок, в отладчике Chrome будет ошибка:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fn' of undefined
```

Comment: _в отладчике Chrome будет ошибка_ - или не будет.

Comment: Не понял Вас, что Вы хотели сказать.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/imports-loader